# Don't know what I did wrong with the logical operator "OR"

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

I don't find my mistake in the following formula

```
=if(AB207<=DATE(2019,8,1),(Z207*0.075),(Z207*0.15);OR if Date =(#N/A)(Z207*0.15))
```

I want the Formula to multiply the cell Z207 with 0.15 if the "value" is `#N/A`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my own problem is:

```
=IF(NOT(ISNA(AB207)), IF(AB207<=DATE(2019,8,1),(Z207*0.075),(Z207*0.15)),(Z207*0.15))
```